# Different values for static variable in each child

Tags: php, class, variables, static

here is my problem :

I want to have different values for a static variable in each child (I don't want to instantiate the class) :

```php
abstract class Model {
    protected static $table;
    
    static function setTable(){
        if(!static::$table){
            // ClassName in plural to match to the table Name
            static::$table = strtolower(static::class . 's');
        }
        return static::$table;
    }
}

class Service extends Model {
}

class Categorie extends Model {
}

class Information extends Model {
    static $table = 'infos'; // Overrides ClassName + s
}
```

And now I want to call setTable() for each child without using `new` :

```php
Service::setTable(); // Return "services"
Categorie::setTable(); // Return "services"
Information::setTable(); // Return "infos"
Categorie::setTable(); //Return "servicies"
```

In fact, the real interest is here to create classes for each table without thinking at which table I need to access.

Any Ideas ?
If you have any Ideas on how to 'clear the static cache' that could also be a solution...

Comment: Those classes aren't related in any way though. Did you miss to extend them?

Comment: Sorry, re-wrote the code to get it simpler, I forgot to extend them when I wrote the question...

Comment: Please copy/paste the real code and remove anything unrelated instead. The code you've posted doesn't give the result you've posted. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/Zho59)

Comment: i just copy your code in phpfiddle, use static to all class and print_r all ouput is ok. where is your problem? [example](https://3v4l.org/AgTcP)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini - That's not their code though. You've added things that's missing in their code. They seem to want to use the class names in some situations

Comment: I just added the other static properties that were not added. the code is the same.

Comment: Yes, you added other static properties that their code doesn't have. And the `getTable()` method uses the class name in case the $table variable is empty so we don't know if that is the case for those classes without that static variable defined (in their code) or if they simply missed it here. We need to see their actual code to understand what's really going on or we're stuck making assumptions and guesses.

Comment: Weird, this code is working on my computer with php 7.3.1. Here's [a version that works as I was explaining](https://3v4l.org/o1VW4), updating my post...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think first You should to use extends keyword in class definition.

```
class Service extends Model {
}

class Categorie extends Model {
}

class Information extends Model {
    static $table = 'infos'; // Overrides ClassName + s
}
```

then it will be possibile to use method from Model class

Comment: Sorry, to simplify the question, I re-wrote my classes, I just forgot to extends them.
I edited my question, thank you ! ;)